# Remove Associated Checkbox Values from Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have (2) checkboxes: 1) Numbers, 2) Countries. When you check either of these checkboxes an associated form appears: (Associated Number -> 1, 2, 3) and (Associated Countries -> Nigeria, Morocco, Sierra Leone). When you check any checkboxes in these associated forms all the checked values get pushed in an array called “checkedValues.”

How can I specifically remove the associated values of `1) Numbers (1, 2, 3)` OR `2) Countries ("Nigeria", "Morocco", "Sierra Leone")` from the checkedValeus array, when `1) Numbers` or `2) Countries` from the Main Category is unchecked?

For example, if Numbers in main category is unchecked remove all its associated values from the checkedValues array.

```js
const numbersForm = document.querySelector('.numbers');
const countriesForm = document.querySelector('.countries');
const numbersCheckbox = document.querySelector('#numbersCheckbox');
const countriesCheckbox = document.querySelector('#countriesCheckbox');
let checkedValues = [];

numbersCheckbox.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if (numbersCheckbox.checked) {
        numbersForm.style.display = 'block'
    } else {
        numbersForm.style.display = 'none'
    }
})

countriesCheckbox.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if (countriesCheckbox.checked) {
        countriesForm.style.display = 'block'
    } else {
        countriesForm.style.display = 'none'
    }
})

// Push checked values to table
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.num');
const country = document.querySelectorAll('.country');
const values = document.querySelectorAll('.values')

const pushToTable = function (e, form) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      form.push(e.target.value)
      console.log(form)
    }
    else {
      form.splice(form.indexOf(e.target.value), 1);
       console.log(form)
    }
}

numbers.forEach(function (sample) {
    sample.addEventListener('change', (e) => pushToTable(e, checkedValues))
});

country.forEach(function (sample) {
    sample.addEventListener('change', (e) => pushToTable(e, checkedValues))
});


function uncheckAllNum() {
    numbersCheckbox.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (!e.target.checked) {
                numbers[i].checked = e.target.checked;
                numbers[i].dispatchEvent(new Event("change"))
            }
        }
    })
};
uncheckAllNum()

function uncheckAllCountries() {
    countriesCheckbox.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < country.length; i++) {
            if (!e.target.checked) {
                country[i].checked = e.target.checked;
                country[i].dispatchEvent(new Event("change"))
            }
        }
    })
};
uncheckAllCountries()
```

```css
.numbers {
  display: none
}

.countries {
  display: none
}
```

```html
 <div class="categories">
  <h2>Main Categories</h2>
    <input type="checkbox" id="numbersCheckbox">Numbers
                        <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="countriesCheckbox">Countries
</div>

<div class="numbers">
  <h3>Associated Numbers</h3>
    <input class="num values" type="checkbox" value=1> 1
                        <br>   
    <input class="num values" type="checkbox" value=2> 2
                        <br>
    <input class="num values" type="checkbox" value=3> 3
</div>

<div class="countries">
  <h3>Associated Countries</h3>
    <input class="country values" type="checkbox" value="Nigeria"> Nigeria
                        <br>   
    <input class="country values" type="checkbox" value="Morroco"> Morroco
                        <br>
    <input class="country values" type="checkbox" value="Sierra Leone"> Sierra Leone
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what you want. You can then get the array from the checked values.

Comment: @WaisKamal  I wish it was, but it isn't. Just as an example, if I check both Numbers and Countries and check 1, Nigeria, Morocco then uncheck 1) Numbers it returns an empty array. This array should still contain the country values Nigeria, Morocco as the 2) Countries checkbox hasn't been unchecked.

Comment: You didn't fully get me. After unchecking, you can simply query the numbers and countries checkboxes, check which ones are checked, put them in an array and return that array. Your code is unchecking the boxes correctly, so the problem is definitely in generating the array of selected boxes.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @WaisKamal. Where would this new array of selected checkbox values be stored in the js script?

Comment: Wherever you would like to!

Answer (score 1):

**First of All**, for in both `uncheckAllNum` and `uncheckAllCountries`, I don't see any need to put that logic inside functions as long as you are only executing them once from the same code, and if you intend to use it later you'll have a problem where you keep adding unnecessary event listeners for the same element that all do the same job.

**Secondly**, You can use the same event listener to handle toggling the display of the forms and updating the checked status of the checkboxes. This will help to minimize your code and make it neater.

**Finally**, you don't need to keep track of the toggled checkboxes, you can make use of the `:checked` pseudo-class and `document.querySelectorAll()`.
You can do something like this to get all the checked checkboxes:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.country:checked, .num:checked')
```

And if you need to get the values of all checked items, you can do something like this:

```js
const getChecked = () =>
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.country:checked, .num:checked')].map(
    element => element.value
  )
```

> Where it uses the spread syntax `[...value]` to transform the NodeList to an array which allows the use the `.map()` function to map each checkbox element to its value.

You can use `getChecked ()` to get an array of the values of selected checkboxes instead of `checkedValues` in your code.

A working example with refactored javascript code: [Example on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pwh2ocm8/)